# How can you make the *ngIf more compact?

Tags: html, angular

Is it possible to somehow put the condition for changing the icon in one line?

**Example #1**

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="isMenuCollapsed" [ngIfThen]="open" [ngIfElse]="close">
</ng-template>

<ng-template #open>
    <fa-icon [icon]='["fas", "bars"]'></fa-icon>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #close>
    <fa-icon [icon]='["fas", "times"]'></fa-icon>
</ng-template>
```

**Example #2**

```
<fa-icon [icon]='["fas", "bars"]' *ngIf="isMenuCollapsed"></fa-icon>

<fa-icon [icon]='["fas", "times"]' *ngIf="!isMenuCollapsed"></fa-icon>
```

Comment: You can make a property that contains icons in your component and return the correct icons based on the condition there. So you don't need to use `*ngIf` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, with method for example:

```
<fa-icon [icon]='getIcon()'></fa-icon>
```

In TS something like:

```
getIcon = () => isMenuCollapsed ? ["fas", "bars"] : ["fas", "times"];
```

Comment: Note that this is terrible performance-wise, as using methods in input / property bindings will force change detection to run on basically any event, and it will traverse the whole application tree. While this may not be an issue now, it may cause issues  later on in the development and will be hard to find. Referer to many articles (e.g. [this one](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496)) to read more about it.